# Analysing server (VPS) before hosting a government website

Tags: ddos, web-hosting

Hosting a government website would definitely increase reputation, but it would also bring higher chances of the hosting server getting attacked by DDoS attacks.

It's a cPanel based VPS. What basic steps should I take to minimize DDoS attack to the server?

Comment: We have already covered ddos mitigation on this site, and it isn't done at server level.

Answer (score 2):

Distributed Denial of Service Attacks can only and solely be mitigated by preventing traffic of reaching your infrastructure in the first place. There are simple proviers like  cloudfare, but more in depth approaches will require you to work together with your ISP(s) considering you are only running a VPS I would look at Cloudfare as I doubt you will have the budget or expertise to set up such a system yourself.

My **personal** 2 cents:

First of all, hosting a government website, depending what type of data you use, can make you liable if data is lost or compromised. It seems that currently you have little or no clue what you are actually doing and this might leave other people their data at risk. Do note that if anything goes wrong, depending on the country or region you reside in, you can be held legally liable with high fines or imprisonment as a result.

Answer (score -3):

DDOS attacks are difficult to control, a firewall as a first step and must be a hardware firewall that blocks 99% of attacks but is relatively expensive and is not offered by every provider.

For cPanel, CSF (ConfigServer Firewall) is very good choice. It can prevent server from d/Dos attack, but as much as hardware firewall.
Thank you

You need do the following setting to prevent DOS Attack.
1) Open the CSF configuration file

```
/etc/csf/csf.conf
```

2) then, search for option called

```
 CT_LIMIT
```

and change this to

```
CT_LIMIT=60
```

,now here 60 is the max no.of connections from an IP to your server ( choose this value according to your server usage )
3) Now search for option called

```
CT_PORTS
```

.This option is used to specify the port for which you want prevent DOS attack.E.g : if you want to prevent the DOS attack to apache and DNS – port 80 and port 53 , change

```
CT_PORTS = “”
```

to

```
CT_PORTS = “80,53″
```

4) Save the file and restarted the CSF firewall.

Comment: Sorry but firewalls do not help against DoS, if the traffic reaches you it's already too late.

Comment: The solution you show does not work against tcp syn attacks where ip spoofing can be used.